# Jquery Mobile - Disable Form Button styling

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to overwrite the jquery mobile form button settings?

I want to use an image as my button active / selected states -  but I'm struggling to disable the code & styling thats automatically added..

Is it possible to disable the styling?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Can you add the scoped html and the css using the image to resolve this issue?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15987014/750216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm I think you're asking how to use a custom icon in a button, try looking over this documentation:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

> **Using 3rd party icon sets** 
> You can add any of the popular icon libraries like Glyphish to achieve the iOS style tab that has large
>   icons stacked on top of text labels. All that is required is a bit of
>   custom styles to link to the icons and position them in the navbar.
>   Here is an example using Glyphish icons and custom styles (view page
>   source for styles) in our navbar:

If you need to disable the button look here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html

disable disable a form button

```
$('[type='submit']').button('disable');
```

If you need to theme the button look here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller

UPDATE:

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/JZJny/

JS

```
$('.imageClick').click(function() {
    alert('I have been clicked'); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">  
    <div class="content">
        <img class="imageClick" src="http://condo69.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/images/clickhere.363151626_std.jpg" alt="click" height="42" width="42" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Phill, Cheers for your help - I actually want to use a image as a button rather and disable all the custom styling as it doesnt fit with my page design.

Comment: cheers Phill, Will this work within a form though - it is specifically a form button that I want to alter...  cheers for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

To disable automatic styling you can change default selector using CSS3 :not(), for example, or just change it to something else:

```
<script>
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.button.prototype.options.initSelector = ".onlyMyButtons";
    // default: "button, [type='button'], [type='submit'], [type='reset'], [type='image']"
});
</script>
```

via http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html