# How to remove jQuery Mobile styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I chose jQuery Mobile over other frameworks for its animation capabilities and dynamic pages support.

However, I'm running into troubles with styling. I'd like to keep the basic page style in order to perform page transitions. But I also need to fully customize the look'n feel of headers, listviews, buttons, searchboxes... Dealing with colors only is not enough. I need to handle dimensions, positions, margins, paddings, and so on.

Therefore I struggle with extra divs and classes added by jQuery Mobile in order to override them with CSS. But it is so time-consuming, and it would be way faster to rewrite css from scratch...

Is there a way to load a minimal jQuery Mobile css file ?

Or should I look towards an other mobile framework ? I need to handle page transitions, ajax calls, Cordova compatibility, and of course a fully customizable html/css...

Comment: I had the same problems, start from scratch isn't an efficient method but the best for me. However, to be finish my project on time I implement the jquerry css mobile and delete most of it...
+1 for your question if some one have an answer

Comment: The ideal way would be to delete the style you do not want from the jquery CSS file. Then create a fresh file with the same class names and customise them as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Indeed, I started with the "structure without a theme" css. I'm going to follow your advice and remove the useless css. However, it would be great to prevent extra (useless) html to be added to the markup. Is there a way to configure jQuery so that it does not add extra styling markup ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Methods of markup enhancement prevention:

This can be done in few ways, sometimes you will need to combine them to achieve a desired result.

- Method 1:

  It can do it by adding this attribute:

  ```
  data-enhance="false"
  ```

  to the header, content, footer container.

  This also needs to be turned in the app loading phase:

  ```
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
  });
  ```

  ***Initialize it before jquery-mobile.js is initialized (look at the example below).***

  More about this can be found here:

  http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UZwpj/

  To recreate a page again use this:

  ```
  $('#index').live('pagebeforeshow', function (event) {
      $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = false;
      $(this).attr('data-enhance','true');
      $(this).trigger("pagecreate")
  });
  ```
- Method 2:

  Second option is to do it manually with this line:

  ```
  data-role="none"
  ```

  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LqDke/
- Method 3:

  Certain HTML elements can be prevented from markup enhancement:

  ```
   $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.keepNative = "select,input"; /* jQuery Mobile 1.4 and higher */
        //$.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select, input"; /* jQuery Mobile 1.4 and lower */
   });
  ```

  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/gAGtS/

  ***Again initialize it before jquery-mobile.js is initialized (look at the example below).***

Read more about it in my other tutorial: **[jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling/)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's not so easy to understand the main differences (pros and cons) between each method.

Answer (score 11):

...or just use the official, [theme-less version of the CSS](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) built specifically to allow the design of a custom theme while maintaining all of jQuery Mobile functionality.

You don't have to fight with hacks and overrides all the time and you get a lighter CSS.

Win-win.

edit: Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014609/how-to-stop-jqm-from-styling-a-page)

Comment: This is by far the simplest, I dont understand why the overly complex way of the accepted answer has the highest up votes!

Comment: @LaurenceCope Have you ever tried to mix jQuery mobile pages with jQuery pages and navigate between them? jQuery mobile likes to infect the entire domain.

Comment: @Yako this is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest i'm fairly disappointed that jQuery mobile didn't provide us with a relatively style-free starting kit, to work merely with what you have said: Ajax, transitions, cordova...

Overriding the generated css classes is absolute madness, but I have done some skunk work and I managed to reduce the uncompressed css file size from a whooping 233kb to merely 27kb, while keeping the important aspects of the css such as transitions, one-page viewing, etc. This way you start almost as you would start with an empty css file.

Perhaps I will upload the file on Github, if there's any demand for it. I wish to do some more testing to see that I didn't leave anything significant behind.

Comment: I can send you the file via email if you wish, you can pm it to me but I must admit that I have carried on to Ionic.. After overly banging my head against the wall with how long it takes jQuery Mobile to do pretty much anything! Ionic on the contrary has great and modern css to start with, and when you combine it with Crosswalk it just truly feels like a native app. I would recommend using Ionic on the long run. ;)

Answer (score 0):

as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0, the `data-enhanced` data attribute was added to most of components. Setting this as true attribute will cause jQuery mobile to ignore style enhancement for the component, so you'll have to style the element by your own.

additional information about this in the jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 release notes here
http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/

Comment: This sounded promising but unfortunately this does not seem to work for selects in jQuery Mobile 1.4.5

Comment: @Vincent this may sound silly, but did you try without the 'd' at the end, such as `data-enhance="false"`? As far as I can see it's still available in their data reference in https://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/ but they seem to be removed the 'd' for whatever reason. You may also need to configure some flags prior to initialization, just as the link states.

Comment: I did not try it without the d.  Strange that they would rename it that way, then again, without the d probably makes more sense but only if true is the default and setting it to false prevents jQuery from enhancing the element.  And yet they seem to be doing it the other way around which makes no sense to me.  Sigh.  Anyway, I ended up simply applying data-role='none' to the element and that works like a charm even without setting init flags.

Answer (score -6):

i m nô expert but i would love to share à weird method with you . Actually, it s very hectic task : what you need is to edit the jqm css line by line by deleting the property values just leave them blanks before ; you have just to look after the desired sections of the CSS file to adjust or delete value

Do not forget to attach your link rel of your own CSS at the head of your HTML page

I hope it will work for you