# jQuery Mobile: Override disabled="disabled" style

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Using jQM v 1.4.0
I've tried to override the grayed out style (`<input type="text" disabled="disabled">`) with:

```
input[type="text"]:disabled
{
    opacity: 1.0 !important;
    color: black !important;
}
```

But it's still greyed out and hardly visible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Mobile enhances the input and creates a textinput widget which inserts the input into a div.  When disabled the DIV is assigned the class ui-state-disabled, so you can override the opacity like this:

```
.ui-state-disabled {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/g8WSd/1/)**

You can use the widget methods to enable/disable the input:

```
$("#btnEnable").on("click", function(){
    $("#myText").textinput("enable");
});

$("#btnDisable").on("click", function(){
    $("#myText").textinput("disable");
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I just wanted to make it a bit more visible and disabled at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:disabled` in your css:

http://jsfiddle.net/YT65W/

**Edit:**
This way works with normal elements.. I misread sorry :/

I think this [How to remove jQuery Mobile styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987014/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling) will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't remove the "disabled" attribute to make it usable?

```
$('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: I don't want it enabled. Just more visible

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `input[type="text"][disabled="disabled"]` as selector.