# Swipe pages using Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

please any one suggest how to Swipe Pages using query mobile left/right

`var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');`

not returning to first page

Answer (score 2):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JB22E/4/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Share QR</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />   
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="article1">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
                <h1>Articles</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Article 1</p>
                <a data-role="button" id="add-dynamic-page">Add new dynamic page</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
                <h1>Footer</h1>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="article2">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
                <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
                <h1>Articles</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Article 2</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="article3">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
                <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
                <h1>Articles</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Article 3</p>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#article1', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#add-dynamic-page', function(event){  
        if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        {          
            var nextPageId = parseInt($('body [data-role="page"]').length)+1;
            $('[data-role="page"]').last().after('<div data-role="page" id="article'+nextPageId+'"><div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer"><h1>Articles</h1></div><div data-role="content"><p>Article '+nextPageId+'</p></div><div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></div></div>');
        }
    });       
});

$(document).off('swipeleft').on('swipeleft', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){    
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {    
        var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;         
});

$(document).off('swiperight').on('swiperight', '[data-role="page"]', function(event){   
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {      
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;            
});
```

This is an example I created few months ago. You will find everything you need + more. Just swipe to see how everything works, you can even click "Add new dynamic page" to see how this example handles dynamically added pages.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I just found it.  This is a perfect solution for what I want to do.  The killer for me is the awful CSS that gets included like all the text shadows and things like that.  Is there a way to have the functionality without the styles?  Or will I need to try and override them all?

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987014/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling