# jquery mobile - navigate through pages using drag and swipe gestures

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, draggable, swipe

I would like to navigate to different pages using the swipe gestures. And what I mean by that is when I tap and drag the page, the page should slide/drag with the swipe gestures but only change the page when it reaches a certain point, like the facebook app or whatsapp.

I saw these post:

[Using swipe gestures to change pages in multi page jquery mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797331/using-swipe-gestures-to-change-pages-in-multi-page-jquery-mobile-application)

[Swipe pages using Jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086317/swipe-pages-using-jquery-mobile)

But in these, there's only the swipe gesture, meaning you can't tap and drag the page. How can I drag and swipe the pages? I hope I was clear. If not please ask. Thank you.

html:

```
<!--    User page-->
    <div data-role="page" id="page0" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>xyz</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page0" data-icon="user"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1" data-icon="home"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="action"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h1>User</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h3>&copy; Kakar Nyori 2015</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--    home page-->
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>xyz</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page0" data-icon="user"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1" data-icon="home"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="action"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h1>All</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h3>&copy; Kakar Nyori 2015</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--    Action page-->
    <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>xyz</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page0" data-icon="user"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1" data-icon="home"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="action"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h1>Action</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h3>&copy; Kakar Nyori 2015</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, jQuery Mobile was not made with this in mind. For this to work you would need to find a way to delegate change page process during the sliding animation which is impossible in current jQuery Mobile application. Changes to jQuery Mobile 1.5 will make this possible, but who knows when it's going to be released. It should happen in next few months .... fingers crossed.

Comment: @Gajotres ohh!.. Then how does whatsapp/facebook have that feature in their UI?

Comment: I told you jQuery Mobile was not made with this in mind. Whatsapp/Facebook got nothing to do with jQM. They are built in React Native so the final result is a full native app, not same underperforming hybrid app. Then again look at my jQuery Mobile scores, if anyone knows about this topic it's me.

Comment: Both Android and iOS. Though you may also look at Xamarin and AppAccelerator. If you want a classic hybrid mobile framework, Frmework7 has the closest approach. Look at this example: http://www.idangero.us/framework7/#.VboPUPmqpBd. Ionic doesn't have nothing similar.

Comment: Ok. I will look into that. Thank you.