# jQuery Mobile: Turn off all mobile styling for a div

Tags: jquery-mobile

[I found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987014/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling), but had no luck getting it to work for me. I am trying to implement a [jQuery Spinner](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/) on my mobile page, but I do not want it to have any jQuery mobile styles.

**CODE:**

In masterpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
    });

    $(document).on('pageinit', function () {        
        $.mobile.silentScroll();
    });
</script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

Control:

```
<td class="diary_control_cell" data-enhance="false" data-role="none">
    <div data-enhance="false" id='noMobileHere'>
        <input type="text" name="OtherTravelersCountTextBox" id="OtherTravelersCountTextBox" value="60" min="0" max="100"  runat="server" data-enhance="false" data-role="none"/>                                                
    </div>    
</td>
```

Though it is made into a spinner, the UI created is still contained within the `<td>` and `<div>`, so you would assume that the `data-enhance="false"` (at least one of them) would still apply. When I turn off the spinner, the `data-enhance="false"` does work. Is there a better way to turn off jQuery Mobile styles for a small portion of the page?

**Edit**

To resolve this issue, I removed the jQM classes causing the issue using the following line (after adding the id noMobileHere to the div containing the spinner:

```
$('#noMobileHere').find('div').removeClass('ui-btn');
```

Comment: Check second solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184234/jquery-css-and-js-to-limited-elements/21185237#21185237

Comment: I tried those solutions, but they did not work for what I want. I think this is because I am making the input a jQuery spinner after the jQuery mobile scripts have loaded. Turining off the mobilization for all inputs is also not ideal for me.

Comment: I also tried to keep `.diary_control_cell` native with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [JQM API for textinput](http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/#option-enhanced) - the attribute you want to set is called `data-enhanced` (you are missing the **d**).

If you don't want JQM to touch your input, set the attribute on the actual element, not any of it's parents.

```
<input data-enhanced="true" ... />
```

As this will tell JQM "the input is already enhanced".

Should work.