# jtsage-datebox theme override

Tags: jquery-mobile, themes, datebox

I am using JQMobile 1.4.5 and datebox 4.1.1. I have a custom theme. Latest as of this message.

My code does work to display a calbox or timeflipbox, the problem is, datebox uses (inherits?) the theme of the underlying JQMobile. I want it to use the standard look of a jtsage databox widget. However, the class ui-btn (and others) is applied and the buttons appear too large and colored as if part of the themed site.

I have searched around and seen mention of a JQuery Mobile attribute:

data-enhance="false"

as described, it is supposed to suppress any enhancement. However, I have observed that it does nothing.

How do I instruct datebox not to allow JQM classes from being applied to the output?

Comment: I did try to specify a non-existent theme as follows:

`data-options='{"mode":"calbox","themeDate":"z","theme":"z"`

Datebox does pick up on it, though it still uses the "ui-btn” class, this is from the source:

 `class="ui-datebox-griddate ui-corner-all ui-btn ui-btn-z”`

I also tried specifying an empty string for the option `"themeDate":"","theme":”” `
what is created is a hanging chard:

`class="ui-datebox-griddate ui-corner-all ui-btn ui-btn-“`

In these cases, JQM falls back to using the default button styling)

Comment: Perhaps I can solve this by making a new theme for the datebox “d” and specify that with 

data-options='{"mode":"calbox","themeDate”:"d","theme”:”d”

But that is a lot of working compared to what i was hoping for, an option to pass to Datebox which instructs it to create the widget and pass it back without any further enhancement by JQM.

Comment: I somewhat solved this by creating CSS with a selector from datebox as follows:
    `.ui-datebox-griddate.ui-btn{
 width: 36px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove jQuery Mobile styling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987014/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling)

Comment: please note [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987014/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling) is a detailed explanation about `data-enhance=false` (among other methods to prevent JQM appliyng the styles)